# tuple of tuple of tuple in ocaml

Tags: ocaml, tuples, concatenation

I have :

```
type 'a box =
  | Item of ('a * 'a box)
  | Empty
```

I need to create the function `concat` :

```
val concat : 'a box box -> 'a box
```

Concatenate a box of boxs. The elements of the argument are all concatenated together (in the same order) to give the result.

I dont inderstand how to create a varible like `'a box box`.

I tried to do :

```
let elt  = Item(1, Item(2,Empty)) 
let elt2 = Item(elt, Item(20, Empty)),
```

But its failed! do you know why?

Comment: I'm thinking the type should be `'a box -> 'a list`, are you sure it's `'a box box`?

Comment: Let me point out that your `Item` constructor is very unconventional. Usually, people do `Item of 'a * 'a box`, which means `Item` has 2 fields. However, you did `Item of ('a * 'a box)`, which means `Item` has 1 field that is a tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create an element of type int box by doing :

```
let elt = Item(3,Empty)
```

And now you can create an element of type int box box, by putting this thing in a box :

```
let elt2 = Item(elt,empty)
```

(box is really only the list type)

With a list it would be :

```
let elt = [3]
let elt2 = [elt] (* which is [ [3] ], the list containing one list, which contains 3*)
```

Regarding your own example, the second one fails because you're trying to create a box containing two different things : a box and an integer. But a box can contain only one type of things.

Comment: I tried to do : 
let elt = Item(1, Item(2,Empty))
and
let elt2 = Item(elt, Item(20, Empty)), 
But its failed! do you know why?

Comment: 1) `and let` should just be `and` 2), in `elt2 = Item (elt, Item(20,Empty))`, you have a type error because the type variable (`'a`) is `int box` but you have `int`.

Comment: you're correct!
I tried elt2 = Item(elt, Item(elt, Empty)), it's work!
Thnx

Comment: The first try fails because you're trying to create a box containing two different things : a box and an integer. But a box can contain only one type of things.  The second works because you put two int boxes in your box, and that is correct.

Comment: updated your answer with the comment you just made, since it completes it.

Comment: I don't know how to accept your edit. I don't see it on the main page, but I see it on the edit page. And I don't know how to accept it, I guess I have to accept it, right ?